# Setting WindowStyle and AllowTransparency in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a simple usercontrol in my MainWindow.  I am trying to create a simple Window Template that is easily protable. I have a usercontrol and this seems to serve my purpose so far well...kinda...

If I set AllowTransparency and WindowStyle in the usercontrol the project compiles successfully but in the MainWindow in the control I get Object Not Set to Instance of...  And the entire control is underlined.  All good if I set in MainWindow.  I can live with this but not the desired result.

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cntl="clr-namespace:Rtg"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="525">
    <!-- if I add windowstyle and allowtransparency here all good -->
    <Grid>

        <cntl:test1 WinTitle="test window framing">
            <cntl:test1.PlaceHolder1>
                <Grid Background="Orange">
                    <TextBox BorderBrush="Transparent" Text="Content in placehoder:" Height="35" Width="175" Margin="0,10,270,0" Background="Transparent" FontSize="16" ></TextBox>
                    <Button Width="100" Height="35" Content="click me" FontSize="16"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </cntl:test1.PlaceHolder1>
        </cntl:test1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
 public test1() {
      Window win = Application.Current.MainWindow;
      win.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
      win.AllowsTransparency = true;
      InitializeComponent();
      ctrTest2.Title = WinTitle;
  }
```

Been web developing for the last 15 years WPF is somewhat pretty new to me.

Is this Normal Behavior for WPF?
Is there away Around This so I can set window Properties in the usercotrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Error.  I was sending one of my functions an int so that I knew which window was loading.  Because no windows or variables are initialized when the app is not running, Visual Studio's decided that my integer was out of the bounds of the array.  Adding a simple if statement around the above code fixed all issues.  Picky Picky WPF.

Kevin,  I was unsure of what you meant by View Model.  After Reading some the xaml.cs or UserControl in my case would be the ViewModel correct?

here is my fix.

```
if (LoadingWindow > -1 && Application.Current.Windows.Count > LoadingWindow) {

    // Load Window 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public test1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      ctrTest2.Title = WinTitle;
      //Need to do it after Initialization
      Window win = Application.Current.MainWindow;
      win.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
      win.AllowsTransparency = true;
  }
```

A more "WPF" way of handling it would be to create a ViewModel and Bind the properties

```
  public class MainViewModel : INotifiyPropertyChanged{

   private WindowStyle _windowStyle;

   public WindowStyle WinStyle {
    get{
   return _windowStyle;
       }
   set{
   _windowStyle = value;OnPropertyChanged("WinStyle");
   } 
  }
}
```

And in the XAML

```
WindowStyle="{Binding Path=WinStyle}"
```

Comment: Before or after does not matter.  I get the same error.  I believe that would only matter if MainWindow was null.  But the constructor has already been called and MainWindow is in the process of Initializing.

Comment: That is really weird, I actually created a demo project and tried and it worked fine for me. Maybe try it with the viewmodel and bind it as a property.